# Custom SQL Server driver

Tags: c#, sql-server, sockets, driver

I had a crazy thought about writing my own SQL Server driver to make it work something like non-blocking http client, so it won't be thread thirsty and could handle lots of db queries within one thread.

I tried to look over google for some guidelines about implementing SQL Server client protocol, but found none really, where do those guys get information about it when they write own implementations for PHP or python?

I need a really low level to be documented so I can implement all phases of working with a connection through sockets. And would be really nice to have a an example in c# language. :)

Comment: Have you actually broken the standard driver or maxed it out or overloaded it?

Comment: no, i just want to run it in non blocking manner, i have limited count of threads i can run at one time so i want to stick as much users as possible to single thread ;) and actually I don't really know why MS hidden it's TDS implementation and reveal only ADO part of it :( I mean they leave higher level wrapper and for some reason won't give access to lower one, i on something like opentds project and feel jealous because they have it, and i dont.. :(

Comment: why would anyone downvote this? it's a legitimate question, asked using the proper q&a format. sure, it may be overkill to implement your own sql driver. but there's nothing inherently wrong with attempting this, or wanting to do it for the sake of a little self-indulgence or as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 2):

I regularly use the existing [Async functionality in the .NET SQLClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zw97wx20(v=VS.80).aspx), this easily allows additional threads to handle the database operations.

I'm not sure how you would really handle multiple non-blocking operations in the same thread.

Comment: i'll you know when I'm finished, it's just a fun case, but maybe will work really nice.

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL Protocol specs:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=91ef5106-944a-41e1-b3a0-5bd3f2356f32&displaylang=en

Without knowing anything factual about it, I would guess that PHP et al, use either the native MSSQL API or they use the standardized ODBC - warping around at the protocol level is just asking for it.

Comment: what is native mssql api you mentioned? and what is standardized ODBC? is there some standart for SQL db base type protocol?

Comment: ODBC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity

Native: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937733.aspx for when you live in unmanaged country as PHP, Python run-times do.